# How to calculate median per group in big dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I imported the `csv` file from desktop and first calculate cube root transformation. I would like to calculate the `median` per group. The table looks like this (i.e. 1 character column + 149 numeric columns):

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
# Import data frame
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/yinc1/Desktop/test_R.csv", header = TRUE)
head(df)


# Perform cube root transformation 
df_cube_root <- cbind(df[1], df[,2:149]^(1/3))
df_cube_root


# Take the median per group
library(dplyr)
df_cube_root %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(Med_per_group = median(as.numeric(df_cube_root)))
medium_per_group
```

When I run this chunk of code, it goes wrong and returns:

```
Column `Group` is not found
```

How should I change the code?

Please find below my data when running `dput(df[1:20,1:5])`:

```r
structure(list(ï..Group = c("12AD_F", "12AD_F", "12AD_F", "12AD_F", 
"12AD_F", "12AD_F", "12AD_F", "12AD_F", "12AD_M", "12AD_M", "12AD_M", 
"12AD_M", "12AD_M", "12AD_M", "12AD_M", "12AD_M", "12AD_M", "12WT_F", 
"12WT_F", "12WT_F"), ATG_PE16.0_22.5 = c(0.02084415, 0.170488266, 
0.032702913, 0.040343933, 0.043272897, 0.051219846, 0.027884681, 
0.064906247, 0.053067268, 0.077767998, 0.140123352, 0.080211375, 
0.101552477, 0.112449923, 0.064881822, 0.090127597, 0.06552084, 
0.054710809, 0.050431982, 0.0427724), Phosphatidylethanolamine..16.0_16.0. = c(0.03193568, 
0.109490593, 0.043206657, 0.041405041, 0.057716584, 0.052915294, 
0.035309818, 0.058013016, 0.041524004, 0.049855731, 0.089821153, 
0.059233229, 0.093928705, 0.046509845, 0.04415071, 0.065380665, 
0.057015153, 0.048773789, 0.045162392, 0.053227769), Phosphatidylethanolamine..16.0_16.1. = c(0.00468836, 
0.048401312, 0.011536122, 0.007585562, 0.011125738, 0.01611854, 
0.010694161, 0.014169938, 0.009804969, 0.013677251, 0.039440742, 
0.011876313, 0.02945088, 0.022079965, 0.01218537, 0.011572354, 
0.011805721, 0.016142917, 0.005502517, 0.007498949), Phosphatidylethanolamine..16.0_18.1. = c(0.094810122, 
0.682954208, 0.17729218, 0.128228583, 0.232379304, 0.214266287, 
0.176554235, 0.213738303, 0.133376481, 0.179952952, 0.591409132, 
0.238990631, 0.46130994, 0.274109352, 0.189368586, 0.203585912, 
0.231057661, 0.340129184, 0.173689226, 0.211021092)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There‘s a closing bracket missing in your summarize code.

Comment: I added it now, it said `Column "Group" is not found` still cannot run.

Comment: After readin in your data with read.csv, can you update your question with the output from `dput(df[1:20,1:5])`.

Comment: Once you hrenamed your first column, does `by( df_cube_root[ , 2 ], df_cube_root$Group, median )` provide you with the results you are looking for, at least for that one column?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the issue in your `dput()`. The first column is not called `Group`, but rather `ï..Group`. There are some wonky extra encoding characters there.

Use `rename()` to fix it.

```
df <- df %>% rename("Group" = 1)
```

Comment: Yep, that‘s acommon/annoying issue when readin in csvs into R. I had this quite often myself.